# List<T>.FindAll() delegate issue with WCF based class

Tags: wcf, list, serialization, delegates

I have a class of "Customers" something like:

```
[DataContract]
public class Customer 
{
    [DataMember]
    public CustomerID {get; set;}
    [DataMember]
    public Name {get; set;}
}
```

In my client, I get a List and then I want to use one of the .Find() methods on it:

```
List<WCFService.Customer> customers = WCFService.CustomerClient.GetCustomers();
WCFService.Customer customer = customers.Find 
    (delegate (WCFService.Customer thisCustomer)
    {
         return thisCustomer.Name == "fred";
    });
```

When stepping through code, however, the "thisCustomer" objects never has a value.

I am assuming that this has something to do with the serialization of the class when it is created, but I am wondering if there is some simple way to get around this or perhaps a better approach altogether.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you GetCustomers is returning but things look weird. I would expect that you have an instance of WCF proxy which you call to get customers..

```
var proxy = new WCFService.CustomerClient();

var customers = proxy.GetCustomers();

var singleFred = customers.FirstOrDefault(z => z.Name.ToLowerInvariant() == "fred");

var allFreds = customers.Where(z => z.Name.ToLowerInvariant() == "fred");
```

The service would have a method along these lines

```
public interface IMyService
{
   IEnumerable<Customer> GetCustomers();
}
```

When adding service reference to your client you can opt to use different collection type then Array by going to advanced settings of the add reference dialog and selecting different Collection type. I would select Generic.List.

Comment: Yes - I have everything as a Generic.List.  My next step was lambdas.  In the interface it is: List<Customer> GetCustomers();.  I am curious if the original problem is a serialization issue.

Comment: I think that there may be another deeper issue that the class is not getting fully populated and this is just a symptom.  Changing things to the way Petar suggested help uncover it.  I will update if that is true after some investigation...

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this slightly simpler code?

```
customers.Find(cust => cust.Name == "fred");
```

Does it work?